# Minecraft crashes when creating a new game

Tags: 11.10, java, minecraft

So, just upgraded to Oneiric and I find there are quite a lot of bugs... One of them is when I try to launch Minecraft and create a new game, it crashes. I get this [error code](http://pastebin.com/xJD8gRqF).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug with minecraft+ATI fglrx drivers, nothing you can do about it will solve this combination, not even Oracle's JRE, its not a Openjdk problem.

You have 2 options:

- [Remove fglrx drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68306/how-do-i-restore-default-video-drives/68312#68312) and try to run with standard ones
- Install [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu), install [Oracle's Windows Java-jre](http://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp) on your wine bottle and run minecraft with it `wine java.exe -Xms256M -Xmx256M -jar /opt/minecraft/Minecraft.jar`

Recommend the 2nd one, gl.

Comment: If you need further instructions on how to install the jre to your wine bottle ask, ill include them later but they are easy, basically after you installed wine you need to type `wine <nameofthejavainstaller.exe> and the rest is just like a windows install. After java is installed run the command given to start minecraft, happy blocking! :D

Comment: Ok, got it. I prefer not to run Minecraft in Wine though. What do you mean by "the standard ones" when removing the fglrx drivers ?

Comment: The bug/fault you have is reported to be generated by fglrx drivers (ATI cards), you have an ATI card correct?

Comment: Yes, indeed. I believe nVidia cards don't use ATI drivers :P

Comment: just making sure :) use the link on the first choice, it describes how to remove the fglrx packages from your system and revert to the open source ones. after that you should be able to run with (this) fault.

Comment: Ok ! So basicly, the open source drivers is just when don't install the additional drivers ? And wouldn't it be simply to just remove the additional drivers within the Additional Drivers menu ?

Comment: Also true, but there is already a guide for total removal and reset (some ppl still have problems with "just removing" using additional drivers tool), hope this helped!