# your system is running in low graphics mode with an ATI Radeon x550

Tags: 12.04, ati

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix “The system is running in low-graphics mode” error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

After yesterday automatic update of Ubuntu 12.04.01 at the first boot I get the message "your system is running in low graphics mode" and i cannot start my desktop normally.
The update was mainly for the Xorg (~100 MB) so I guess the problem is there.
The only way I'm able to use my Ubuntu now is after I executed the command
"sudo cp xorg.conf.failsafe xorg.conf"
The side effect is that Unity starts with the 2D version and I'm not able to get the 3D version back.
The ATI driver for this graphic card are no longer available so only the open ones can be used.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I had encountered the same problem after upgrading the Linux kernel to 3.2.0-32 this morning. And the problem was solved by running the AMD Catalyst display driver which can be downloaded at http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Kernell was updated, I had the same problems sometimes. Try purge drivers

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx-amdcccle
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx-updates fglrx-amdcccle-updates
```

If than is all alright, install proprietary drivers again https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer, but the proprietary drivers are not anymore part of the installed packages so I cannot purge them (already done before), so the solution must be somewhere :). Plus my graphic card is not anymore supported

Comment: Then you have to restore default fglrx drivers. Try to look here http://askubuntu.com/questions/68306/how-do-i-restore-default-video-drivers

Comment: when I try to follow the steps i get stopped at the ´sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64´ it tells me that the libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 and libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 packages are not available

Comment: Try this 'sudo apt-get --purge remove fglrx*'

Comment: done already but as I said i have nothing from fglrx so it doesn't remove anything at all

Comment: If this didn't help, only thing I can think of is reinstalling your system, but you can have more luck trying google some solution or waiting for somone else to help you.