# configure modeline Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: monitor, xrandr

I am running Ubuntu 12.04.2 in dual boot with Windows 7 on the same drive.

In Windows, I customize my refresh rate for my 2nd monitor with the program powerstrip. When I export my Linux modeline and create a new mode for Ubuntu, I get the following errors when I try to change my 2nd monitor to that mode:

```
~$ xrandr --output DFP3 --mode "1400x1050_2" 
xrandr: Configure crtc 1 failed
```

My question is, how can I remedy this problem? I need to have the same custom timings as Wndows.

**My specs are:**

- Ubuntu 12.04.2 (3.5.0-23-generic)
- AMD driver catalyst-13.1-linux-x86.x86_64
- P6x58D premium motherboard
- 6 gigs of ram
- 23 inch Asus monitor
- 15 inch DIY monitor.

Answer (score 0):

The following steps are needed to change the display mode using xrandr:

#### 1. Get modeline

To change the geometry of an attached screen we first need to calculate the modeline for a desired resolution with `gtf` or `cvt` (whatever is installed):

```
cvt <xres> <yres> <refresh>
```

For a resolution of 1400x1050 at 50Hz this will give us the follwing modeline:

```
# 1400x1050 49.97 Hz (CVT 1.47M3) hsync: 54.11 kHz; pclk: 100.00 MHz
Modeline "1400x1050_50.00"  100.00  1400 1480 1624 1848  1050 1053 1057 1083 -hsync +vsync
```

#### 2. Define new mode

Copy and paste the modeline to add it as a new mode named `1400x1050_50.0` (or any other name we choose) for xrandr:

```
 xrandr --newmode "1400x1050_50.00"  99.88  1400 1480 1624 1848  1050 1051 1054 1081  -HSync +Vsync
```

#### 3. Attach mode to monitor

We then attach this new mode to our monitor, e.g. `DFP3` (note that this will error if we had chosen a mode not supported by the graphics card driver):

```
xrandr --addmode DFP3 1400x1050_50.00
```

#### 4. Change mode

After this was successful we then can switch to this new mode using

```
xrandr --output DFP3 --mode 1400x1050_50
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I should have mentioned that I already do the above steps. Everything goes fine until I change mode. That is when I get the error. Now, I know that my graphics card (HD5850) is able to get the mode in Windows, so I think it should work in Ubuntu as well. I believe that the problem may simply be because the drivers for linux are not good compared to Windows drivers.

Comment: Yeah, this is a driver issue then. Try to [purge fglrx](http://askubuntu.com/questions/68306/how-do-i-remove-the-propretary-ati-drivers) to test if the open `radeon` driver does better.