# aticonfig still shows old config after replacing video card

Tags: drivers, upgrade, ati, catalyst

I had a system with AMD 7950 video card installed, 
than I upgraded the video card to R9 280X and reinstalled
the driver to the latest version  AMD Catalyst™ 14.1 Beta Driver

I did this for reinstall the card config:

```
 sudo aticonfig --initial -f --adapter=all
```

but now I still get the old version:

```
aticonfig --odgt --adapter=all

Adapter 0 - AMD Radeon HD 7900 Series
            Sensor 0: Temperature - 29.00 C
```

Comment: A note to everyone: try removing the proprietary ATI drivers first (by following the steps in this question: [How do I remove the proprietary ATI drivers?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/68306/how-do-i-remove-the-proprietary-ati-drivers) and then install the drivers again for the new card.