# Lubuntu Ati driver?

Tags: gpu-driver

I wanted to know what driver version of ati/amd for sapphire hd 4650 1 gb agp 8x,on lubuntu 13.10 ? 
I didn't find any good for it with display or something.

I have SApphire hd 4650 1024 MB AGP 8x
Processor Sempron 3300+
Ram : 1 GB (2x 512 MB DDR1)

Answer (score 0):

I just use the AMD Ceder driver, which comes pre-installed into Ubuntu (I haven't used Lubuntu, but I imagine the same driver would be used). Although I don't have a Sapphire 4650 (I *do* have a Radeon HD 5450), I can say that this is a fairly stable.

However, if you want to try another driver, the only thing I can recommend is the "official" drivers from AMD. Personally, I've found these drivers to be a bit less stable, but perhaps you will have better luck than me. If you want to give these drivers a try, you can get them [HERE](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download).

PS: if you decide to remove the drivers, perhaps [THIS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68306/how-do-i-remove-the-propretary-ati-drivers) page can help.

Comment: OK,thanks for the informations,anyway i tryed the amd official,but didn't work,i suppose i could make a bootable usb with ubuntu 12.04 ls or something like that who have ati support.