# Can't get rid of "previous version of fglrx" and installing AMD's drivers fails

Tags: 12.04, drivers, ati, fglrx

I tired out the **fglrx** driver form **Additional Drivers** program and they were not what I thought it would be, so I downloaded the drivers from **AMD**... but when I run the program  like this `sudo ./amd-driver-installer-13.35.1005-x86.x86_64.run` I get this:

```
[Error]A previous installation of fglrx driver detected to be loaded.
User must uninstall existing fglrx driver 
or run install with force option. 
Forcing the installation is not recommended.
```

I tried to remove the driver rom **Additional Drivers** Program again and tried to re-install... still the same message, then I did:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx
```

Then tried the installer again. STILL the same message. What do I have to do to completely get rid of **fglrx**???

(P.s I did reboot after every move)

Comment: reboot and then try again. If that fails, how did you install the driver the first time ?

Comment: I had the AMD driver (the one from their site) installed first. Then I wanted to see what the one that ubuntu offers is capable of, so I went in additional drivers program and installed the driver from there. When I saw that it wasn't better than AMD's I did the steps above. removed and then tried to re-install. btw too late for the reboot and stuff. I already forced it and now it's worse. It starts up with a warning that it runs in a low graphics mode. Any ideas? Or should I install ubuntu from scratch? (To be honest that seems easier than all this trouble)

Comment: First, remove the driver using apt-get as you have. Next run the uninstall script. `sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh` . See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/68306/how-do-i-remove-the-propretary-ati-drivers But in general, never "force" anything (apt-get or otherwise) unless you know what and why you are doing so.

Answer (score 0):

I do the installation a bit different. You could try this:

```
# Add the installer script it its own directory. For example amddriver
cd amddriver

# Create deb packages for precise (12.04) or quantal (12.10)
sudo sh ./amd-driver-installer-13.35.1005-x86.x86_64.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/precise

# Force overwrite the older packages with the new ones
sudo dpkg --force-overwrite -i *.deb
```

This works for me for removing:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev*
```

Comment: 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

And still Can't install the driver.

Comment: @DeusDeceit I have edited my answer. Perhaps this helps you now.

Comment: But it says `forcing` is not recommended... Why is it not recommended and is it safe?

Comment: Forcing is not advised. See my comment above. If rebooting does not work, update your question with the information I requested.