# AMD graphics drivers

Tags: 14.04, ati, graphics, fglrx

I have a new laptop with dedicated graphics card and I decided I will go with Ubuntu 14.04. All is just fine and I love it but the repos for graphics drivers from Canonical are just well... old  .Is there any problem if I install my graphics drivers from [AMD's official website](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux%20x86#amd-catalyst-packages) and not from Software Updater?
 It's just that from there i get the latest and greatest.I read the realease notes and 14.04 is [supported](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/Latest-LINUX-Beta-Driver.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience:  Go ahead and install the drivers, but before you do print out some de-install instructions!

Answer (score 0):

There should be no problem if you use the drivers from the official website. In fact, the driver setup will offer you the option to create a distribution-specific driver package, a .deb file which you can install with `sudo dpkg -i <filename>.deb`. This way, it is cleaner to install and remove the driver.

Go ahead and do it, and make sure you know what you're doing. There is some helpful information on this website:

[What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-proprietary-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx)

[How do I remove the proprietary ATI drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68306/how-do-i-remove-the-propretary-ati-drivers)

Answer (score 0):

Just be aware that when you update the Linux Kernel, you may (will?) need to update the driver, as it depends on the kernel.  This is the attraction of using the repository for everything, as it will get updated automatically.  So, try the repository first and see if any of their versions are good enough.  Otherwise, you may find yourself in

I'm no expert, so I don't know the details, but I think there may be some way to automate this.