# Black Screen after Grub menu with a underscore

Tags: drivers, 13.10, graphics, freeze

Recently after trying to upgrade Ubuntu 13.10 to Ubuntu 14.04 my laptop will boot up until the grub menu and after selecting my OS it would just give me a black screen with a underscore at the top

The problem seems to have something to do with the graphic drivers from what I've been able to find.

Computer Model:Dell Inspiron 1564
Processor: Intel core i3 
System Chipset: Intel HM55

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were using the proprietary drivers you may need to revert to the open source drivers, and then you can experiment with re-enabling them.

During the boot, hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd>  This will get you to the Grub boot options screen.  From there, you will want to choose 'Network' which takes a while to complete, and 'Root' which will drop you into a tty terminal.

From there, the procedure in [how-do-i-remove-the-proprietary-ati-drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68306/how-do-i-remove-the-proprietary-ati-drivers) will remove the ATI drivers and load the open source drivers.