# Installation hanging on black screen

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, system-installation

I tried to install Ubuntu over a year ago and was almost able to get it right, aside from my ATI graphics card. Well, 4 months ago I bought a new Nvidia graphics card and thought I'd give Ubuntu another try. Unfortunately, Ubuntu has it out for me.

I've used both CD and USB flash drive, and I had the same issue with both. Once I restart and prepare to install Ubuntu it takes me to an orange and yellow gradient screen and then, shortly after it takes me to a black screen with a blinking underline character at the very top.

I left the computer for over 4 hours last night and came back to find that it was STILL STUCK on this black screen. I'm currently running two hard drives: one has 1TB and the other is 177GB.

My specs are as follows:

---

- Intel i5 2500k 3.3Ghz Quad Core
- EVGA NVIDIA GTX 750TI 2GB VRAM
- 8GB dual channel RAM
- Biostar H61MH

---

Any help in fixing this issue is most appreciated.

Comment: Do you see anything of what is shown [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions). Might it be possible to get to the "Ubuntu CD Advanced Welcome Page Options" by hitting e.g. the space key repeatedly? If THAT isn't *shown*, how about following it with pressing F1, F2 ... F6

Answer (score 0):

There's a link for working on black screen at [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it).  You may need to remove the proprietary drivers, and a good link for that is at [How do I remove the proprietary ATI drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68306/how-do-i-remove-the-proprietary-ati-drivers)

Answer (score 0):

***SOLVED*** 
Played around a bit and figured out a solution to this issue. Turning on nomodeset in advanced boot options as well as space pressing spacebar during the black screen fixed the issue. I'm now running Ubuntu v13.14!