# Fglrx always hard-crashes my hybrid-GPU laptop. How can I disable radeon and use only i915?

Tags: drivers, graphics, xorg, radeon, i915

My computer only seems to boot when I have radeon.modeset=0. Xorg still loads the radeon drivers, which causes it to use llvmpipe for OpenGL rendering, which in turn makes my CPU fans sound like they're launching into space.

How can I force Xorg to load i915?

Update (6/19/2014):

I tried the instructions posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68306), but it didn't seem to change anything. I had already purged fglrx before. Here's my xorg log: http://sprunge.us/QRTI. You can see that while it fails to load `fglrx`, it still loads `radeon`. And it still is using llvmpipe:

```
$ glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.4, 256 bits)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the radeon drivers from the system, and revert to the open source drivers. [Here is a link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68306/how-do-i-remove-the-proprietary-ati-drivers) with the appropriate procedure.

Comment: I followed those instructions (I had already purged fglrx before), but no change. I've updated my question with my Xorg log.