# uninstall ati catalyst control drivers ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, ati, graphics, uninstall

I followed the steps described on

http://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/ubuntu-amd-catalyst-install

and now my ubuntu gives me the blank screen .. i tried a lot of things to uninstall ati catalyst but still unable too do so. So can any body please guide me how to do so

---

Edit:

I can connect to the internet in recovery mode.

My Graphic card is Amd Radeon hd 6490M

Comment: ya i am able to do so in recovery mode

Comment: amd radeon hd 6490M

Comment: first it gave me initct1:Event failed  and then it said xserver-xorg-video-radeon ia already the newest version

Comment: i think its .deb coz when i used the command locate fglrx , it showed me the .deb

Comment: i used Ubuntu AMD Catalyst install and it was totally gui based. Can you elaborate What is the package name after the installation

Comment: but how do i go to software centre when i am not able to access the desktop

Comment: i am able to access just the terminal

Comment: i think you are asking for this  ---- AMD Catalyst™ 14.4 Proprietary Linux x86 Display Driver

Comment: The answers at [http://askubuntu.com/questions/68306/how-do-i-remove-the-proprietary-ati-drivers][1] were written for ATI, but work equally well on AMD.


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/68306/how-do-i-remove-the-proprietary-ati-drivers

Answer (score 1):

Find the exact package name after the installation with `dpkg -S [PACKAGE NAME PART]` command.

Either:

```
sudo dpkg -S amd
```

Or :

```
sudo dpkg -S catalyst
```

It will list the names of the packages. Find the exact package name.

Then use the `dpkg -r` command to remove the package:

```
sudo dpkg -r [PACKAGE NAME]
```

EX: `sudo dpkg -r amd-driver-installer`

then reboot

Comment: response is no installed package matching fglrx

Comment: is there any another away of getting the backup from my  /var/www folder

Comment: are you saying the name for the .deb  package

Comment: amd-driver-installer-14.10.1006.1001-x86.x86_64.run i think this was the package name but not sure weather .deb or .zip

Comment: no installed packege matching .......

Comment: Please run `sudo dpkg -S amd` or `sudo dpkg -S catalyst` in terminal and tell the output.(Copy and paste here)

Comment: i am just getting the feeling that this should solve the problem

Comment: nope. man i am doomed,  dont know what s wrong ,, i ran each and every command but still gets stuck to blank screen .. lot of my data is there in /var/www