# Why Can't I install the Intel Graphics Installer app?

Tags: graphics, intel

Every time I follow the steps to use it, I click the file I downloaded and it pulls up Ubuntu Software Center with an error: 
Dependency not satisfiable: libglib2.0-0 (>=2.37.3).
Now I thought I might have to download libglib, so I went into the command line and entered the command:
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-0
And boom, downloaded and installed.
When it still didn't work I restarted, still same error message.
I've tried fifteen different approaches to getting my graphics card to operate like it should in the last hour and a half just trying to circumvent this issue when I couldn't resolve it. Someone please be my hero and just tell me how to make the installer work.

Comment: try `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --reinstall glib2.0` and see if that works

Comment: Already tried that. Didn't work. Good idea though.

Comment: if you've been using aptitude, take this as a lesson learned and stick with apt-get from now on

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you downloaded the official genuine not guaranteed to work properly graphics installer from Intel at [01.org](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2014/intelr-graphics-installer-1.0.5-linux), you first do the download, then you go to the dask and type 'intel' at which point the intel-linux-graphics-installer should appear so you can run it, or open a terminal <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and enter the command

`intel-linux-graphics-installer`

but *before* you do this, you should also know how to [uninstall the driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68306/how-do-i-remove-the-proprietary-ati-drivers) *should you possibly need to*.

From the terminal window that you can get to by pressing <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd>, enter the commands

Try to completely remove your ATI drivers from your system:

```
sudo apt-get purge fglrx*
```

Remove your xorg.conf

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Reinstall xorg completely

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri
```

Re-configure Xorg

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Reboot

If you can't get to the terminal as described above, use the recovery mode, and enter the root mode.  Use the command `mount -o remount,rw /` to get the disk into writeable mode, and enter the commands above.

Comment: Major issue with that is that I've already messed around with xorg a bunch. I can't figure out why, but no matter what I do I end up with broken packages. Xorg won't work on my machine... one of the issues I also attempted rectifying.
So yeah, I've purged and removed and reinstalled a couple times with no results.

Comment: @AshtonBrown It's painful.  I ended up using the oibaf drivers instead.  Faster than the xorg, not as unstable as xorg-edgers.  They work really well in my dell laptop with intel graphics.  I may see some improvement using the intel driver, but last time I did that it was really, really bad.

Comment: I haven't tried the oibaf drivers yet. If you recommend em' I'll give em a shot.

Comment: @AshtonBrown They worked without issue on a dell inspiron 15r, and an HP pavillion dv7-4263, both of which would not do 3d well prior to that.  They include instructions to revert to stock drivers via ppa-purge.  The repository can be found at launchpad  (https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers).  I sometimes get a little tearing, but they have updates 2 or 3 times a week.