# Low-graphics-mode problem

Tags: amd-graphics

I tried this fix: [How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)
And could not uninstall the driver.
I tried all the ways including [this one on AMD support](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/Catalyst-Linux-Installer-Notes.aspx)

I am still stuck on this mode and cannot get rid of it.

How can I get out of low graphics mode and properly install the driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedures at [How do I remove the proprietary ATI drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68306/how-do-i-remove-the-proprietary-ati-drivers) work with both the ATI and AMD drivers, and will help you get out of this mess.

The basics:

in a terminal, type the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge fglrx*
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
sudo reboot
```

Comment: That worked thanks, now the ubuntu tells me it doesn't use the graphic card.. What should i do?

Comment: I've had good success using the oibaf drivers - these are advanced xorg drivers, but not as advances as the xorg-edgers, so they remain stable.  Use them both on an HP and a Dell Laptop.  They are located at https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers

Answer (score 2):

### **System running on low graphics ubuntu**

Easy solution is not to do any graphic driver changes just run below command and it will solve **system running on low graphics** problem permanently , Tested on more than 10 system

**# sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade**

Answer (score 2):

When you face the same problem System running on low graphics ubuntu.

#### 1. just go to the tty mode pressing(Ctrl+Alt+F1).

#### 2. login with the username or password.

### 3. Run this command (sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade)

#### 4. Reboot