# Error processing package fglrx. Package fglrx is not configured yet

Tags: drivers, nvidia, dependencies, fglrx

I faced with this message after reinstalling fglrx package. The reason of reinstalling fglrx was solve the problem with nvidia drivers (I tried some answers to solve black screen on system boot or freezing on login). The message below appears when I use `apt-get` command (remove, install etc). So how can I solve this problem?

```
Setting up fglrx (2:13.350.1-0ubuntu2) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode
update-alternatives: error: error creating symbolic link `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules.dpkg-tmp': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package fglrx (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of fglrx-amdcccle:
 fglrx-amdcccle depends on fglrx; however:
  Package fglrx is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package fglrx-amdcccle (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up nvidia-prime (0.6.2) ...No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.

nvidia-prime start/running, process 3001
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 fglrx
 fglrx-amdcccle
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem just by purge fglrx* packages due to unnecessary of ATI drivers (if I'm not confusing something). I have Nvidia GPU, so I've run this:

`$ sudo apt-get purge fglrx*`

That's all. Thanks for this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68306/how-do-i-remove-the-proprietary-ati-drivers).