# Pre-requisites for AMD Graphics Drivers

Tags: 14.04, fglrx, 14.10, amd-processor

I get following error while installing amd graphics drivers-

`Please install the required pre-requisites before proceeding with AMD Catalyst installation. Please check file usr/share/ati/fglrx-install.log for more details.`

But I cannot locate mthis fglrx-install file.Someone help

Answer (score 1):

The file specified by the installer probably does exist. You can open it with gedit for instance :

```
gedit /usr/share/ati/fglrx-install.log
```

Then it will tell you what to install. For me (Ubuntu  15, R9 200 series) it was:

```
apt-get install dh-modaliases.
apt-get install execstack.
apt-get install debhelper.
```

Then try again the install driver, with sudo

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to ensure that you have the Linux headers available.  Open a terminal and enter the command

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

You may also need the build esentials, although I don't think they are required for AMD

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

I would also strongly recommend that you read this article about [removing the AMD drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68306/how-do-i-remove-the-proprietary-ati-drivers) before you try the installation.

The log file should be located at `/usr/share/ati/fglrx-install.log`

Comment: Isn't your 2nd command a subset of 1st command? Installing build-essential.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your system does not have the following packages:

**dh-modaliases** and **execstack**

To install these, type the following commands at terminal (execute terminal by Ctrl + Alt + t)

```
sudo apt-get install dh-modaliases
sudo apt-get install execstack
```

OR

```
sudo apt-get install dh-modaliases execstack
```