# Testing Additional Drivers: Can't use mouse or keyboard now

Tags: 14.04, drivers, graphics, keyboard, mouse

I have been using Ubuntu 14.04 with no problems for about 8 months now. I am looking to upgrade my processor, however, due to a few reasons. I wanted to test my graphics one last time before I bought my new processor, so I switched the driver under settings. When I rebooted, nothing works. I load my home screen, but I cannot use my mouse, cannot use any keys, nothing. Just an unresponsive computer. Does anyone have suggestions? I don't know what information is required but I'll provide what is needed once I know. The Graphics card is a MSI Radeon R260x

Comment: Have you tried booting in recovery mode (hold down `Shift` when you boot, select *Advanced menu*, *Recovery mode* and continue on to boot (effectively adding `nomodeset` to your boot options)? You might be able to boot normally and remove the driver causing the issue.

Comment: I got the recovery mode to boot last night, but when I went to change the driver it had already reset to the correct one. I would then shut down again and boot normally, but it would go back to my incorrect settings... Hmm..

Comment: Have a look at [How do I remove the proprietary ATI drivers?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/68306/how-do-i-remove-the-proprietary-ati-drivers), but be aware that it was for an older release so in particular the instruction to reinstall xorg may not be correct on 14.04