# Package operation failed, Cant install any update

Tags: package-management

i recently started getting this error whenever i run an update:

```
Package operation failed, The installation or removal of a software package failed.

Details:
installArchives() failed: (Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 323998 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libgbm1_10.6~git1504210730.700463~gd~t_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgbm1:amd64 (10.6~git1504210730.700463~gd~t) over (10.6~git1504190730.b2e871~gd~t) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libegl1-mesa-drivers_10.6~git1504210730.700463~gd~t_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libegl1-mesa-drivers:amd64 (10.6~git1504210730.700463~gd~t) over (10.6~git1504190730.b2e871~gd~t) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libwayland-egl1-mesa_10.6~git1504210730.700463~gd~t_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libwayland-egl1-mesa:amd64 (10.6~git1504210730.700463~gd~t) over (10.6~git1504190730.b2e871~gd~t) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libegl1-mesa_10.6~git1504210730.700463~gd~t_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libegl1-mesa:amd64 (10.6~git1504210730.700463~gd~t) over (10.6~git1504190730.b2e871~gd~t) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libgl1-mesa-dri_10.6~git1504210730.700463~gd~t_amd64.deb ...
De-configuring libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (10.6~git1504190730.b2e871~gd~t) ...
Unpacking libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (10.6~git1504210730.700463~gd~t) over (10.6~git1504190730.b2e871~gd~t) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libgl1-mesa-dri_10.6~git1504210730.700463~gd~t_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (10.6~git1504210730.700463~gd~t) over (10.6~git1504190730.b2e871~gd~t) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libgl1-mesa-glx_10.6~git1504210730.700463~gd~t_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 (10.6~git1504210730.700463~gd~t) over (10.6~git1504190730.b2e871~gd~t) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libgl1-mesa-glx_10.6~git1504210730.700463~gd~t_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 (10.6~git1504210730.700463~gd~t) over (10.6~git1504190730.b2e871~gd~t) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libgles2-mesa_10.6~git1504210730.700463~gd~t_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgles2-mesa:amd64 (10.6~git1504210730.700463~gd~t) over (10.6~git1504190730.b2e871~gd~t) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libglapi-mesa_10.6~git1504210730.700463~gd~t_amd64.deb ...
De-configuring libglapi-mesa:i386 (10.6~git1504190730.b2e871~gd~t) ...
Unpacking libglapi-mesa:amd64 (10.6~git1504210730.700463~gd~t) over (10.6~git1504190730.b2e871~gd~t) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libglapi-mesa_10.6~git1504210730.700463~gd~t_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libglapi-mesa:i386 (10.6~git1504210730.700463~gd~t) over (10.6~git1504190730.b2e871~gd~t) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libxatracker2_10.6~git1504210730.700463~gd~t_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxatracker2:amd64 (10.6~git1504210730.700463~gd~t) over (10.6~git1504190730.b2e871~gd~t) ...
Preparing to unpack .../xserver-xorg-video-intel_2%%3a2.99.917+git1504201932.75037e~gd~t_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking xserver-xorg-video-intel (2:2.99.917+git1504201932.75037e~gd~t) over (2:2.99.917+git1504181930.7eaf59~gd~t) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (10.6~git1504210730.700463~gd~t) ...
Setting up libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (10.6~git1504210730.700463~gd~t) ...
Setting up libgbm1:amd64 (10.6~git1504210730.700463~gd~t) ...
Setting up libegl1-mesa:amd64 (10.6~git1504210730.700463~gd~t) ...
Setting up libglapi-mesa:amd64 (10.6~git1504210730.700463~gd~t) ...
Setting up libglapi-mesa:i386 (10.6~git1504210730.700463~gd~t) ...
Setting up libwayland-egl1-mesa:amd64 (10.6~git1504210730.700463~gd~t) ...
Setting up libegl1-mesa-drivers:amd64 (10.6~git1504210730.700463~gd~t) ...
Setting up libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 (10.6~git1504210730.700463~gd~t) ...
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf because link group x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf is broken
update-alternatives: error: unable to remove '/etc/ati': Is a directory
dpkg: error processing package libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 (10.6~git1504210730.700463~gd~t) ...
Setting up libgles2-mesa:amd64 (10.6~git1504210730.700463~gd~t) ...
Setting up fglrx (2:15.200-0ubuntu0.2) ...
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf because link group x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf is broken
update-alternatives: error: unable to remove '/etc/ati': Is a directory
dpkg: error processing package fglrx (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of fglrx-amdcccle:
 fglrx-amdcccle depends on fglrx; however:
  Package fglrx is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package fglrx-amdcccle (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libxatracker2:amd64 (10.6~git1504210730.700463~gd~t) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Setting up xserver-xorg-video-intel (2:2.99.917+git1504201932.75037e~gd~t) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64
 fglrx
 fglrx-amdcccle
Error in function: 
Setting up libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 (10.6~git1504210730.700463~gd~t) ...
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf because link group x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf is broken
update-alternatives: error: unable to remove '/etc/ati': Is a directory
dpkg: error processing package libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up fglrx (2:15.200-0ubuntu0.2) ...
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf because link group x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf is broken
update-alternatives: error: unable to remove '/etc/ati': Is a directory
dpkg: error processing package fglrx (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of fglrx-amdcccle:
 fglrx-amdcccle depends on fglrx; however:
  Package fglrx is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package fglrx-amdcccle (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: run sudo apt-get purge fglrx* then try sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade see more at http://askubuntu.com/questions/68306/how-do-i-remove-the-proprietary-ati-drivers

Comment: Thanks Aravinda, I did what you said  and my system worked fine

Comment: so that is excellent and why dont you mark your answer ? so that some one can easily spot it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Suggested by Aravinda above, this is what I did:

I ran

`sudo apt-get purge fglrx`

then

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` .

See comments above.