# Can't login after installing AMD drivers in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: ati, catalyst

As mentioned above, the login screen loops after installing the graphics drivers.
I have tried to login via the terminal and purge it all again, but it does not help. I have tried three times, and all with the same outcome. Both via Synaptic package manager and the terminal, also same result.

Anyone experienced this and maybe have a solution!?

I have reinstalled Ubuntu 15.10, without trying again.

Answer (score 0):

From your login screen, switch to terminal using `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F1`.

Type the following:

```
sudo mv ~/.Xauthority ~/.Xauthority.backup
sudo service [name_of_display_manager] restart
```

Try it out and let me know if this works.

Comment: I saw that solution in here, and tried it. Did not work.

Comment: I am sorry to hear that, why don't you try the solutions posted on this link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/620869/15-04-installed-fglrx-amd-ati-drivers-wont-boot