# Ubuntu booting onto black screen?

Tags: boot

I am getting this weird problem after installing ATI Drivers, my system is booting into a black screen after the Ubuntu loading screen.

I can access my original installation via LiveCD but got no clue about what to do here.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 x86 on an Asus laptop.

Answer (score 0):

There are two links which will help you:  You can try to [troubleshoot the black screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) or you can [remove the ati drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68306/how-do-i-remove-the-proprietary-ati-drivers).

I would recommend removing the ATI drivers, but the choice is yours.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response but I suppose my terminal commands only affect the LiveCD installation and not the one on my hard drive.

Comment: When you boot your system without the live CD, hold the left shift key so that you can boot into a recovery mode - if you choose the 'root' option, you will be able to execute the commands required to remove the ATI drivers.

Comment: Already tried that but it won't boot into recovery either..

Comment: Link only answer from a user with 4,000 rep ? -1

Comment: @markkirby I know, I should go into great detail, but I am basically pointing at an answer previously pointed, and should instead mark this as duplicate.

Comment: @VilleJuutila You can perform operations (run commands) to affect your installed Ubuntu from a live dvd/usb. So it WILL affect the install, not just the live system. Think of it like this, the files for Ubuntu are on your HDD, when you boot a live usb you can access and modify those files, so you can make changes to the OS without booting it.