# Can't login to my Ubuntu 14.04 after system update

Tags: 14.04, command-line, permissions, login

When I try to log it shows the desktop background then shows a black screen and then It takes me back to the log in screen...

I can't even log in as guest, I tried with `Ctrl + alt + F1` and I can log in from terminal. I did some of research and tried solutions like:

`sudo chmod -R ug+rwx /home/[username]`

`chown -R [user-name]:[user-name] /home/[user-name]`

`sudo mv .Xauthority .XauthorityBak`

Tried also installing `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-session`

Well but none of them worked, what else can I do?

Comment: What is your video adapter? Did you install any drivers for it? If yes, how you did it?

Comment: Hi, yes I have a Radeon graphic card but installed the drivers long time ago, but everything was working in the normal fashion until the update. I do not remember how I installed the drivers, how can I check if issue is coming from graphic card?

Comment: You could install the drivers a wrong way, if you downloaded them from AMD site.

Comment: But everything was working!, if I would had installed drivers wrong then problem would have occurred long time ago, am I wrong?

Comment: If you install drivers a wrong way, they stop working after kernel update.

Comment: Is there a way to enter into some kind of logs and check if the problem is coming from the graphic card drivers?

Comment: It is 99% that it is related to video drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get into console by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1.

You can login there and install or remove drivers.

If your video adapter is new, run

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall fglrx-updates
```

That will install AMD drivers.

You can remove them by

```
sudo apt-get purge 'fglrx.*'
```

Comment: Hi thanks, the problem was indeed with the graphic card, but your instructions where incomplete, I followed instructions here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/68306/how-do-i-remove-the-proprietary-ati-drivers