# Can't get past ubuntu boot screeen after upgrade to 15.10!

Tags: boot, 15.04, 15.10

I have just upgraded to 15.10 from 15.04 and now my Ubuntu will not get past the ubuntu loading screen? It just hangs...

Managed to get back into the desktop briefly using recovery mode and reinstalled the proprietary drivers, but now I cannot get into anything on any boot option!

Comment: Which proprietary drivers are you running?

Comment: Hi Charles, not sure off the top of my head but I'm using one of the ATI/AMD non-updates one from the additional drivers program.

Comment: I would suggest that you try removing the proprietary drivers and get the system running properly prior to adding them back in.  There was a tutorial on removing the ATI from the command line terminals in [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/68306/how-do-i-remove-the-proprietary-ati-drivers) - I believe that this can be performed from a recovery screen or from a tty.  You might also try adding nomodeset to the kernal parameters at startup

Comment: What do you mean by "loading screen"? The greeter=login-screen or the plymouth-bootscreen=Ubuntu symbol on purple background with spinning dots?

Comment: Hi Byte Commander it is stuck at the plymouth bootscreen. Worth noting that it freezees after two runs of the dots and then stops when all red, and the machine will do a clean shutdown when the power button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I couldn't get it to work and also checked out the link Charles sent me but to no avail.

I reinstalled the system and installed the proprietary drivers again and I got the same symptoms, the system hung on the plymouth screen so this looks like an AMD graphics compatibility issue. Will just have to use the xorg driver untill AMD update it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get back in by holding shift while powering up and booting the older kernel in recovery mode. Got garbage on screen but up/down arrow revealed some options. I enabled networking which does some stuff and returns to same menu, then choose continue booting. In Settings/Other Drivers I disabled proprietary ATI driver and then restarted. I chose the stable (not 'updates') driver then. Seems to be OK now...