# Ubuntu 15.10 doesn't start after install amd drivers

Tags: drivers, ati, 15.10

I have installed amd drivers from the update manager and after that Ubuntu is stacked onthe start splash, somebody can help?
The driver is flgxr updates and the graphic car is an r9 270x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I believe that you need to remove the AMD drivers.  If you can do this from a terminal after booting, great!  If not, then you will need to boot into a recovery mode and try to remove them there.

---

To get to recovery mode, hold your left shift key while Ubuntu boots.  At the grub menu, choose "Advanced Options for Ubuntu, then the line which says "...(recovery mode)"

In recovery mode, choose the 'networking' mode so that you can do a little re-installation work as well.  From here, the instructions are the same in both recovery mode and in a terminal window.

---

Try to completely remove your ATI/AMD drivers from your system:  Please note that these instructions are lifted verbatim from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68306/how-do-i-remove-the-proprietary-ati-drivers)

```
sudo apt-get purge "fglrx.*"
```

Remove your xorg.conf

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Reinstall xorg completely

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64
```

Re-configure Xorg

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Reboot

```
sudo reboot
```

You should be greeted with lightdm, this will default everything x the same way a fresh install would.