# Which version of ubuntu supports my card & how do i install the closed-source driver?

Tags: graphics, ati, radeon, gpu-driver

I want to ask which version of ubuntu supports my card fully: ATi Radeon HD 3650 AGP, and how could i install the closed source drivers on that version on ubuntu? (The reason why i want closed source drivers, becouse open source ones are SLOW and i cannot even play a simple 3d game).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to read  [how to remove ATI drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68306/how-do-i-remove-the-proprietary-ati-drivers)  before you install the new drivers.

You can download and install the video drivers from the AMD website. I have done this for my ATI card in the past, however the open source drivers gave me better performance than these ones.

Download the driver : 
http://www2.ati.com/drivers/legacy/amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13.1-legacy-linux-x86.x86_64.zip

Open the folder you saved the downloaded file to and extract it contents.

[image]

Right click on the file that was extracted and click properties, then click on the permission tab and tick "Allow this file to run as a program".

[image]

After having done this, double click the extracted file - it should ask you for your root password and then it will run you though the setup and install your display drivers.

Comment: Just for sanity's sake, please also review [how to remove ATI drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/68306/how-do-i-remove-the-proprietary-ati-drivers) before you install!

Comment: @CharlesGreen forgot about that do you mind if i put that in my answer ?

Comment: Not at all - it's much easier than answering the question "Why doesn't my display...."!!!

Comment: Thanks, so i searched which ubuntu support my card, and it seems that ubuntu 12.04 supports that driver, is ubuntu 12.04.5 supported too?

Comment: @BucketRocket Your Card will work on all LTS version of Ubuntu, i don't know what you mean by `supports my card fully`. 12.04.5 and 12.04 are the same so yes it will be supported.