# Galium 0.4 on llvmpipe

Tags: drivers, graphics, 15.10, amd-graphics, opengl

I'm totally desperate. I'm trying to install open source video drivers for my R9 270x, but no matter what I do when I run 
`glxinfo | grep OpenGL`
 it shows

```
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.6, 128 bits)
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 11.0.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
```

I've been googling this problem for about 2 days already, read all posts related. Nothing works, nothing helps.

What I did:
added this ppa

```
ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
```

And this one

```
ppa:paulo-miguel-dias/mesa
```

Then

```
apt-get update
```

I looked into xorg.0.log file and found the following:

```
[    45.977] (EE) Unable to initialize PCS database
[    45.977] (EE)   Missing PCS defaults file /etc/ati/amdpcsdb.default
[    45.978] (II) [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
[    45.978] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[    45.978] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[    45.978] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[    45.978] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    45.978] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    45.978] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    45.989] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    45.989]    compiled for 1.17.2, module version = 0.0.2
[    45.989]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[    45.989] (**) FBDEV(2): claimed PCI slot 1@0:0:0
[    45.989] (II) FBDEV(2): using default device
[    45.989] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[    45.989] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    45.989] (II) UnloadModule: "radeon"
[    45.989] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
45.994] (II) AIGLX: Screen 0 is not DRI2 capable
[    45.994] (EE) AIGLX: reverting to software rendering
```

Still nothing. When I first installed Ubuntu 15.10 I managed to install this driver correctly and was using it till I decided to try Crimson AMD Driver yesterday (what a big mistake). I didn't like Crimson driver, so I completely uninstalled it. So now I have software rendering and not able to play games anymore, no solution from the web works.

Comment: Hi Sergey - I would remove the Oibaf drivers, I don't think they are helping you.  You should use `ppa-purge` to do this, other methods will work poorly if at all.  Then  read [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/68306/how-do-i-remove-the-proprietary-ati-drivers) - I know it says "ATI" drivers, but the same methods remove the AMD drivers.  Finally, I would try to re-install the drivers you had before...

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But, I already did everything you suggest and nothing helps

Answer (score 0):

I have the same situation on Ubuntu Xenial.
For now, there is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/1493888) for kernel 4.2+

You should do :

```
sudo ppa-purge oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo ppa-purge paulo-miguel-dias/mesa
reboot
```

Then, you can either stay with the opensource AMDGPU driver or downgrade your kernel to [4.1.15](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.1.15-wily/) and try again.

```
sudo apt install fglrx
sudo amdconfig --initial
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
reboot
```

To diagnose issue, look at your /var/log/kern or dmesg

```
grep fglrx /var/log/kern
dmesg | grep fglrx
```

If you can't reboot, go in recovery mode and work with those command

Good luck :)

Comment: thank you for your answer. what does this command do? sudo paulo-miguel-dias/mesa. Well, I managed to solve this by reinstalling system and looks like the root of the problem was in remains of official AMD driver, that I uninstalled unproperly. So for this situation the real question is: how to uninstall drivers correctly?