# Unable to login after update

Tags: 14.04, update-manager, radeon

After letting system updates run today, cannot login through the UI. Not even as guest. 14.04. The update asked about flgrx or whatever similar name four times, whether configuration should be upgraded and replaced or kept.

Answer (score 0):

Here You have the answear [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop). First use terminal and check rights of Your home folder.

Comment: Well, that long list of voodoo there does not solve it, but thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the AMD drivers altogether to overcome this. As the initial error during the updates seemed to point at it, it seemed a like a good shot. I followed [How do I remove the proprietary ATI drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68306/how-do-i-remove-the-proprietary-ati-drivers). I am no longer recommending Ubuntu to my friends after this additional quirk. The cost over lost productivity is too high.