# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL

Tags: opengl, libraries, shared-library

I'm trying to compile Alephone on Ubuntu 14.04, but I'm getting the issue that -lGL isn't found. Running `whereis libGL.so` returns nothing, even though I've installed libgl1-mesa-dev, mesa-common-dev, freeglut3-dev, and freeglut3. This started after installing the proprietary drivers for the AMD Radeon 2400 HD pro. Due to an error with the installation, though, I removed it, and I think that's the culprit. How do I get the library back?

Answer (score 0):

Running `sudo apt-get install fglrx-dev fglrx-updates fglrx-updates-dev` Fixed the issue. For some reason, I couldn't install all three at once, so I had to install fglrx-dev first, and then the other two were fine.

EDIT: I was mistaken, following the instructions in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68306/how-do-i-remove-the-proprietary-ati-drivers) worked perfectly.