# No desktop Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: xubuntu

I start pc, it goes through bios ok, goes through grub ok, even displays xubuntu splash image (big xubuntu on blue-white background) and stops. I can get in tty1, even log in, but no desktop. Tried startxfce4 only to see fatal server error server already running. How do i get my desktop back, as it was before this problem, without reinstalling my system preferably. Also, im not-native english, linux beginner.

edit: it is dell optiplex gx280, no wifi, no bluetooth, graphics card is eah5450 silent/di/1gd3(lp) with the graphics engine AMD Radeon HD 5450.

Yesterday i turned it off like every day, and today its stuck on black screen.

---

Not fixed, reinstalled.

Comment: Please add a description of your computer (brand name, model, graphic chip/card, wifi chip/card). Can you remember what happened before this problem started (did you install something, was it an automatic update)? It makes it easier for us to help.

Comment: i will check back in few hours

Comment: There might be a problem with the driver for the graphics card. Are you using the free driver? There might also be a hardware problem. Please try *live* with an install USB drive or DVD disk 'Try Xubuntu'. It should work with 16.04.1 LTS or 14.04.1 LTS or 14.04.5 LTS if the hardware is OK.

Comment: live usb xubuntu 16.04 or .10 worked fine, im using manufacturers driver with updates. its definitely software thing, just no clue what. i dualboot with win xp sp3 and they work rock-stable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad that the hardware is OK :-)

The problem might be that the proprietary drivers for Radeon chips are no longer developed/supported. On the other hand, the corresponding free driver is developed and quite good in 16.04.1 LTS and newer versions of Ubuntu.

Please try to switch to the free driver (by removing the proprietary driver). If we are lucky it will work with your graphics card.

This link shows how to remove the proprietary driver for Radeon cards:

[askubuntu.com/questions/68306/how-do-i-remove-the-proprietary-ati-drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68306/how-do-i-remove-the-proprietary-ati-drivers)

Otherwise you can use an older version, where the proprietary driver is still working, for example 14.04.1 LTS. Unfortunately that version of Xubuntu is only supported for 3 years, until April this year. But in the meantime you might find another solution.

Comment: But if the splash image works, how can it be the driver? Or is it some weird linux bug/feature? Also how do i remove the proprietary driver using cli?

Comment: I added a link that shows how to do it.

Comment: Did not help, its the same as before, so it wasnt the driver, but somewhere higher.

Comment: Have you tried with some boot options, for example `nomodeset`? See this link about boot options, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808

Comment: altering boot options did nothing.

Comment: I'm running out of ideas soon. It is an option for you to use an older version - for example Xubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (with end of life in April)? Or try with TahrPup (Puppy Linux based on Ubuntu Trusty Tahr alias 14.04 LTS). See also this link, Old hardware brought back to life, https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2130640

Comment: how do i find out what programs i have installed? ill reinstall, but dont remember the apps i have.

Comment: There are two ways to do it. Either you check which programs you have installed or you make a standard install and add new program packages, when you need them. The latter method is probably better, because you have probably installed (and used) several programs, that you will never use again. Anyway see this link, https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages