# Ubuntu won't start properly after installing new GPU

Tags: nvidia, gnome

I recently acquired a new GPU for my computer. I installed it and tested it (on Windows 10), and it works fine. Now I tried starting Ubuntu on my computer, but it gets stuck on "Started GNOME...". I previously had amdgpu installed on my system, and that worked great with my old graphics card. But with my new graphics card, after removing the amd drivers, it isn't working. I tried installing the recommended Nvidia drivers from the graphics-drivers ppa, but that doesn't work at all. Even proprietary drivers won't work. If anyone knows anything that could help, I would be very grateful.

Comment: boot into recovery mode, remove amd driver then reboot.

Comment: @MahardiBaniadam  It seems that you have overread that part. I have removed the AMD drivers already, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: sorry my bad, after remove amd driver you need Reinstall xorg completely. 
check this link  https://askubuntu.com/questions/68306/how-do-i-remove-the-proprietary-ati-drivers

after that install nvidia driver.