# Ubuntu 18.04 PC boots to black screen and is unresponsive after installing AMD_GPU_PRO drivers for 7870XT drivers

Tags: 18.04

After my latest update to my Ubuntu 14.04 I received errors related to the video.  The PC was no longer able to load screen resolution settings.  I decided that it was time to upgrade my pc anyway so I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 and then to 18.04.  After uploading to 18.04 the issues appears to be resolved but,I noticed when loading games from steam that many artifacts would appear on the screen.  I decided to install the AMD proprietary drivers.  After installing the drivers the PC would boot to the Ubuntu splash screen the first do under the word Ubuntu would illuminate and then the PC goes to a black screen.  I have also notices that my keyboard is active during the ASUS Bios splash screen but, is not responsive once Ubuntu begins to load (if I press <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> the appropriate LED does not illuminate).   Is there anyway to recover this system?

Answer (score 1):

Try <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> when you get the black screen and see if this drops you to a terminal session. 
If this doesn't work try to boot directly to a shell interface, i.e to command line without a GUI at all, no display manager or windows manager whatsoever. You can achieve this through 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' in the grub menu during boot. To make the menu appear see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time).
From the command line you can uninstall the driver you installed, for how to do it see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68306/how-do-i-remove-the-proprietary-ati-drivers). Then just reboot and it should work (to reboot from the command line just type "reboot" and hit enter).