# boot fails with "amdgpu: Fatal error during GPU init" after switching graphics card from Nvidia to Radeon RX 7800 XT

Tags: boot, amd-graphics, nvidia-geforce

Today I **switched** my graphics card from a **Nvidia 1050Ti** to an **AMD Radeon RX 7800 XT**.
Before doing that I switched graphics driver from proprietary nvidea to Nouveau. But that doesn't seem to be sufficient. Now my **Kubuntu 22.04** **boot fails** with

```
[drm:amdgpu_device_ip_early_init [amdgpu]] *ERROR* early_init of IP block <mes_v11_0> failed -19
amdgpu 0000:0c:00.0: amdgpu: Fatal error during GPU init
```

[image]

Luckily I can still start into recovery mode and the resume to normal and that leads to a working desktop. So I do have access to my system which should make fixing it not that hard. Also I have a dualboot system and I can boot into Win10 without a problem, so the graphics card itself is fine.

I expect the answer to my problem to be an adapted version of "reconfigure/reinstall" xserver-xorg like in this [case](https://askubuntu.com/a/68312/887134)!?

I actually tried to install the [radeon driver for ubuntu 22.04](https://www.amd.com/en/support/linux-drivers) afterwards but that was apparently too little, too late.

How do I fix this problem? And is that already how I get the best Radeon driver on my Kubunu? (I play a lot of Steam games on my linux system, so I'm fine with using proprietary Radeon drivers, if that's the way to improve my gaming experience.)

**EDIT:**

as requested, here's the text from installing `amdgpu-install`: (It's mostly mostly swedish, but as you can see, the latest version already seems to be installed.)

```
stephan@blux:~/Hämtningar$ sudo apt-get install ./amdgpu-install_5.7.50700-1_all.deb 
Läser paketlistor… Färdig
Bygger beroendeträd… Färdig
Läser tillståndsinformation… Färdig
Observera, väljer "amdgpu-install" istället för "./amdgpu-install_5.7.50700-1_all.deb"
amdgpu-install is already the newest version (5.7.50700-1653597.22.04).
0 att uppgradera, 0 att nyinstallera, 0 att ta bort och 0 att inte uppgradera.
```

And yes, the `20_radeon_hd6800` file exists as well:

```
stephan@blux:~/Hämtningar$ sudo ls -la /usr/share/grub-gfxpayload-lists/blacklist/
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 23  2023 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Feb 23  2023 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  660 Mär 27  2015 00_header
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   26 Mär 27  2015 10_vmware
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   13 Mär 27  2015 11_virtualbox
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   13 Mär 27  2015 20_radeon_hd6800
```

Comment: Proprietary drivers: Clean out any attempted failed installs. Go to related website, find correct driver software, follow instructions given there to install, reboot at least once to verify the drivers stay in place and are working.

Comment: I know, but I need way more specific instruction than this. I managed on Win10, but changing drivers on Kubuntu is a different thing. The tab for additional drivers in the settings is empty (that's where I could select my nvidia driver.)
The solution might be the same as in the case I linked in the main post but with this step `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64` adapted to my driver situation!?

Comment: After downloading it (Radeon™ Software for Linux® version 23.20 for Ubuntu 22.04.3) appears to be a fairly straight forward thing; https://amdgpu-install.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install-prereq.html#installing-the-installer-package why not try again, and keep an eye on all text that appears, see if there are any details, COPY *all of it* as text into your posting above (**edit** and paste, mark the text as "code")

Comment: Also see if there are any files similar to `/usr/share/grub-gfxpayload-lists/blacklist/20_radeon_hd6800` (blacklisting!)

Comment: ok, maybe this is my mistake: I assumed that amdgpu-install would install amdpgu but now it looks like I only installed the installer which I now have to execute!?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- the "reconfigure/reinstall xserver-xorg"-idea was completely wrong
- downloading the latest "radeon driver for ubuntu 22.04" was a step in the right direction, but it turns out this doesn't install the amd gpu drivers, but the installer, called amdgpu-install, which will install the drivers!

I still had to actually install the drivers. Which was straight forward given the documentation provided by Hannu: [here](https://amdgpu-install.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install-prereq.html#installing-the-installer-package) (this is how you install the installer, once you downloaded the appropriate one from [here](https://www.amd.com/en/support/linux-drivers).

If you click next at the bottum of the page you'll get the [page](https://amdgpu-install.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install-script.html) telling you how to actually use the installer.

Since I'm fine with proprietary drivers I used

```
amdgpu-install --opencl=rocr --vulkan=pro -y --accept-eula
```

to install them. After I did this, I restarted my machine and everything booted fine (and Steam also starts which it didn't before).

Another helpful option is to use `amdgpu-install -help` to see all the possible options.

Comment: ... Congrats! :-)